# How to show expandable and single list view

Tags: android

Is there a way to show expandable and non expandable list in the same list view? 
What I am trying to achieve is to have expandable list view but for items that don't have sub items, and I don't want to  show the arrow expand arrow icon
How how can I do that? Please help
Thanks

EDIT: All what I want is to be able to hide indicator arrow when group is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Basically, you have to hide "expand arrow" when group has no child.
You can achieve this by setting `GroupIndicator` property to null.

For ex :  `getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(null);`

**OR**

2) by checking the children count you can set the indicator like the below code,

```
   if ( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
       indicator.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
    } else {
       indicator.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
       indicator.setImageResource( isExpanded ? R.drawable.list_group_expanded : R.drawable.list_group_closed );
    }
```

For more information about hiding Group indicator, you can refer [this link](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/06/hiding-group-indicator-for-empty-groups.html).

**OR**

3) Create a group_indicator.xml file in drawable folder

```
<item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
<item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrowdown"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/arrowright"></item>
```

Then, define expandable list view like the below code,

```
   <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ExpandableListView>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: That indeed is what I am looking for. The last suggestion won't work because it is always in empty state and that's limitation by android(actually they say it is for performance reasons)

Comment: However in your first suggestion, setting it to null will disable it for the whole list

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can.

Use [BaseExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html)

this class has next methods:
getGroupTypeCount() and getGroupType(int groupPosition)

which you should override.

In simple way you have two type of item. For example Expandable(type 1) and Not expandable(type 2).

getGroupTypeCount() shoul return 2;

override getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
in this method check item's type by item's position.
If item not expandable you should generate View which its look doesn't depend of if it is expanded or not.

I think it is very simple.

Comment: Thank you, not sure I quite got the point around getgroupview, and an example would be really helpful